# Custom File Upload with div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, upload

I want to buld custom file upload system like dropzone.js....
Without `<input>` tag... 
I build this:

```js
var fileSelector = $('<input type="file" name="imageToUpload" id="imageToUpload">');
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#imageToUpload").hide();
  $("#uploadDiv").on("click", function() {
    fileSelector.click();
  });
});
```

```css
.uploadDiv {
  border: 2px dotted lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.uploadDiv:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uploadDiv" id="uploadDiv">
  <small>Click to select <strong>image</strong> for upload.</small>
</div>
```

But how i can take file and work with php and ajax?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2320069/863110) question can help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send FormData objects with Ajax-requests in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery)